# integration by parts on a Lipschitz domain as $\epsilon\to 0$

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde

For a fixed, bounded, smooth domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ and any $u\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ with trace $u|_{\partial\Omega}=g\in L^1(\partial\Omega)$ one can prove that
$$
\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}
\int_\Omega u(x)
\left(\frac{C_d}{\epsilon^d}\int_{\Omega\cap B_\epsilon(x)}\frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)}{\epsilon^2}dy\right)dx
=\int_\Omega u(x)\Delta\varphi(x)
-\int_{\partial\Omega} g(x)\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial n}(x)dx
$$
for any $\varphi\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^1(\bar\Omega)$ vanishing on the boundary.
Here $n=n(x)$ is the outward unit normal to $\partial\Omega$ and $C_d$ is a suitable dimensional constant.

One can convince oneself by Taylor expanding $\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)\approx \nabla\varphi(x)\cdot(y-x)+\frac{1}{2}D^2\varphi(x)(y-x)\cdot(y-x)+o(|y-x|^2)$:
for "interior" points $x$ which are "far away from the boundary" we actually integrate over the full ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap\Omega=B_\epsilon(x)$ in the integral, hence the first order term cancels out due to
$$
\int_{B_{\epsilon}(x)}\nabla\varphi(x)\cdot (y-x)dy=
\nabla\varphi(x)\cdot\int_{B_{\epsilon}(x)} (y-x)dy=0.
$$
It is then a classical computation to check that
$$
\int_{B_{\epsilon}(x)}D^2\varphi(x)(y-x)\cdot (y-x)dy=
|B_\epsilon|tr(D^2\varphi)=2C_d\epsilon^d\Delta\varphi
$$
(the constant $C_d$ is precisely chosen to get the Laplacian in the end, and not some multiple thereof).

For points which are $\epsilon$-close to the boundary the computation is trickier  because the first-order terms do not cancel out anymore, but one can see the normal derivative appearing looking for example at points $x\in\partial\Omega$ and expanding
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{\Omega\cap B_\epsilon(x)}\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)dy
 & \approx \nabla\varphi(x)\cdot \int_{\Omega\cap B_{\epsilon(x)}}(y-x)dy\\
&=\nabla\varphi(x)\cdot \frac{1}{2}|B_\epsilon|\epsilon n(x)\\
&=C'_d\epsilon^{d+1}\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial n}(x).
\end{split}
$$
(Of course not just the boundary points matter and the whole $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\partial\Omega$ comes into play in order to balance the $\frac{1}{\epsilon^{d+2}}\times \epsilon^{d+1}=\frac 1\epsilon$ singularity, this is just to give an very rough idea.)

Although this is probably written somewhere, for my own convenience I went trhough the trouble of justifying carefully all these steps when the domain is smooth, which is easily achieved by working in local charts.
Note that the notion of the trace $u|_{\partial\Omega}=g$ is not completely trivial to start with, since this is a borderline case $p=1$ in the Sobolev scale $W^{1,p}$ (in particular any stable statement should work in $BV$, not just in $W^{1,1}$ I guess).

---

For Lipschitz domains, working in local charts simply becomes a mess, as there is no clear choice of "good" coordinates when $\partial\Omega$ is a Lipschitz graph $t=h(x')$, with locally $x=(x',t)\in \mathbb R^{d-1}\times \mathbb R$.
Hence I would prefer avoiding going through the trouble of reinventing the wheel, if possible:

> **Question:** can anyone give me a precise reference for the corresponding statement when the domain $\Omega$ is only Lipschitz regular?

**Note:** I am NOT asking whether there is an integration by parts formula in $BV$ for Lipschitz domains (I know several good references for that). What I am actually interested in is the fact that this can be retrieved as the above limit $\epsilon\to 0$ as above.

Comment: A bit niche for a precise reference, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe, but it looks such a natural result that I doubt it's never been written... I thought I'd still give it a shot here on MO before spending too many hours adapting my smooth proof. Let's wait and see.

Comment: Fair enough - I hope you find the reference! By the way, wouldn't an approximation argument be more natural than redoing the whole proof? E.g. using the fact that $f$ and $Df$ coincide on an arbitrarily large set with a $C^1$ function.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the interest! The issue here is not really the low regularity of $u$ (no derivatives of $u$ whatsoever enter the statement!), but rather that of the domain $\Omega$. Even if $u$ is, say, $C^1$ or $C^2$ up to the boundary, the proof is still unclear to me when $\Omega$ is only Lipschitz (and I'm actually not 10000% confident that the result holds true)

Comment: Sorry, this should have said $h$ and $Dh$ - I was referring to an approximation of the boundary.

Comment: Ah, I see. But then this becomes tricky, because how do you make sense of "the functional spaces $W^{1,1}(\Omega_\delta)$ converge to $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ as $\delta\to 0$", where $\Omega_{\delta}$ has regularized boundary? Perhaps this is standard, but I'm not aware of anything like that. Can you give a starting reference for this approach, perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there should be a few ways around this, no? For example, could you not consider an increasing smooth sequence $\Omega_j \subset \Omega_{j+1} \to \Omega$? (In which case a function in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ restricts to $W^{1,1}(\Omega_j)$.)